# How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android without root or adb?

Tags: android, screenshot, printscreen

as title says, im trying to figure out how to programmatically take a screenshot in android without root or adb,
what about executing script or simulating android keyevents? im trying to find solution but no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 5.0+, use the media projection APIs. They are somewhat under-documented. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/MediaProjection/andshooter) demonstrates how to take screenshots.

On Android 4.4 and lower, this is not possible, outside of perhaps some security flaws on specific device models.

Comment: The `ScreenshotService` runs in background?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher: If you are referring to that sample app, it is a foreground service, mostly for user controls. There is nothing about the media projection APIs that requires a foreground service IIRC, but you are subject to the Android 8.0+ limitations on background services.